# How to find first term and common ratio when the only given hints is the sum of terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

In a geometric series,  the sum of the first three terms is $304$ and the sum of the first six terms is $1330$. Find the sum of the first seven terms.

$S_3=304$
$S_6=1330$

So how do I find $a$ and $r$? Is there any possible simple way to solve this? I'm so frustrated!

Comment: Solve it simultaneously. I'm guessing you know the formula for $S_{n}$, so just plug the numbers in!

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$S_3=\large \frac {a(1-r^3)}{(1-r)}=304$

and

$S_6=\large \frac {a(1-r^6)}{(1-r)}=1330$

2 equation, 2 unknown - Can you solve ahead?

Answer (score 2):

You know that a geometric series is of the form $a,ar,ar^2,\ldots$, so you have

$$a+ar+ar^2=m$$
and
$$a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+ar^4+ar^5=n.$$
Then we have
$$n=a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+ar^4+ar^5=m+r^3(a+ar+ar^2)=m+mr^3$$
or
$$\frac{n-m}{m}=r^3$$
so now you know the value of $r$ (in the case, the numbers actually work out very nicely). Then there is only one unknown in the equation
$$a+ar+ar^2=m$$
so you can solve for $a$. Once you know both, you can simply add up as many terms as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The sum $S_n$ of the first $n$ terms of the geometric series $a, ar, ar^2\dots$ is given by

$$S_n=a\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$

Now, write down the two equations given by your assignment. Which equations do you get?